# Update Sverchok Tree on Frame Change

Tags: sverchok

I'm using the `Current Frame` output from the `Frame Info` node to create random parameters on each frame. Everything works as expected but if I change the frame to create new values I have to manually update the nodetree.

Is there a way of auto-updating the tree on frame changes (like for example in Animation nodes)?
`Animate layout` and `Process layout` are both checked in the Treepanel.

Answer (score 1):

there is maybe reason you offed in prefs:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the case. But, I found the issue: seems like sverchok doesn't update the Frame Info node inside of a monad. If this is the intended behaviour (for some reason) I feel like there should be some sort of hint or error message.

Comment: aha.monad will be replaced with group node later on. but it have known issues, not only that.